# convert string with array structure back to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have `<input type="text" name="info">` with the value like this:

```
array() {
      [name]=> 'Tien'
      [sex]=> 'male'
      [address]=> 'ABC'
      [code]=> '888'
    }
```

I submit this input to another site (Note that the input value is a string), all I want is convert that value from string back to array `array("name"=>"Tien", "sex"=>"male", "address"=>"ABC", "code"=>888)`. Is possible to convert the string back to array. If yes please help me solve this. Thanks and sorry because my bad English

Comment: How did you come up with this specific format exactly? As deceze said it doesn't seem to be easily serializable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is *serialisation*, i.e. expressing an arbitrarily complex data structure in the lowest common denominator as text. If you simply choose a serialisation format which can easily be serialised and unserialised, this is trivial. I'd suggest to use either [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) and `unserialise` or [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and `json_decode`. Whatever format you came up with there is simply not easily unserialisable.

Answer (score 2):

I can't completely understand your question, but from my best guess, use this form data:

```
<input type="text" name="info[name]" value="Tien" />
<input type="text" name="info[sex]" value="male" />
<input type="text" name="info[address]" value="ABC" />
<input type="text" name="info[code]" value="888" />
```

The other site can then handle it as an array stored within `$_POST['info']`